# How to access current value in a text input field with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate retrieving form values from *an already filled out form* with puppeteer and xpath.

I've already automated FILLING a text input field as follows, but doing the reverse with .evaluate() doesn't work:

```
[fieldHandle] = await page.$x("//label[text() = 'My Label']/../following-sibling::td[1]//input")
await page.evaluate((x, y) => x.value = y, fieldHandle, 'newValue')
```

This is my most recent attempt - still no success...

```
let [fieldHandle] = await page.$x("//label[text() = 'My Label']/../following-sibling::td[1]//input")
let fieldRaw = await fieldHandle.getProperty('textContent')
let fieldValue = await fieldRaw.jsonValue()
```

Hopefully someone out there knows how to achieve this!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using evaluate should work:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(x => x.value, fieldHandle)));
```

Comment: Boom! That worked... Assigning the .evaluate() result to variable was successful!
`let fieldValue = await page.evaluate(x => x.value, fieldHandle)`

Answer (score 5):

This worked in my case

```
const name = await page.$eval("#usernameInput", (input) => {
 return input.getAttribute("value")
 });
```

Comment: Hi, could you please put the code inside code brackets for a better reading experience. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simply..

```
const name = await page.$eval('//label[text() = 'My Label']/../following-sibling::td[1]//input"]', element => element.value);
```